# Using a Web Form to Create a Sharepoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

My Sharepoint site is made up of many Page. Each page is essentially a demo page example: Picking Food off conveyor, Stacking into a Box. I want many people in my organization to be able to contribute to this Sharepoint site. They would contribute by each making their own page on a use-case they have done. Explaining the exact workflow to maintain a standard style of Sharepoint Page creates permission liabilities and some obvious chances to not follow the rules.

**The best solution** would be a web form that asks for certain information (Page name, Page description, as well as some drop down options, and some attachments) when that webform is submitted Sharepoint would create a new page that follows a certain Page design and enters all the information that has been submitted.

I have sharepoint designer but have been unable to automate the transforming a webform into a page.

Any suggestions or directions I should look into would help.